# Python: import of Modules with mutual dependency

Tags: python

I have two files `rest_api.py` and `Contact.py`. Contact is similar to a domain object (contains `Contact` class), while rest_api has functions for setting up the application.

In `rest_api` I have the following lines:

```
from Contact import Contact
...
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
collection = client.crypto_database.test_collection
def dbcollection(){
     return collection
}
...
api.add_resource(Contact,'/contact/<string:contact_id>')
```

In `Contact` I try to do the following:

```
from rest_api import dbcollection

class Contact(Resource):
    def get(self,contact_id):
        result = {}
        result['data'] = dbcollection.find_one({'contact_id':contact_id})
        result['code'] = 200 if result['data'] else 404
        return make_response(dumps(result), result['code'],{"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

This fails with the following error:
`ImportError: cannot import name Contact`

What is the correct way of importing contact, so that it can also use variables/functions from rest_api?

p.s If I move the collection code to a different file, and import that file instead things work, but I assume there is some other way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a circular import dependency, which cannot be solved as such. The problem is, that importing a python module really runs  the code, which has to follow some order, one of the modules has to go first.

I would say that having the support code in a different file would be the proper way to go.

In this case however, the `dbcollection` is not actually needed at import time. Thus you can solve this by removing the import from the module level, into the get function. For example

```
class Contact(Resource):
    def get(self,contact_id):
        from rest_api import dbcollection
        result = {}
        result['data'] = dbcollection.find_one({'contact_id':contact_id})
        result['code'] = 200 if result['data'] else 404
        return make_response(dumps(result), result['code'],{"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

A similar approach would be the following:

```
import rest_api

class Contact(Resource):
    def get(self,contact_id):
        result = {}
        result['data'] = rest_api.dbcollection.find_one({'contact_id':contact_id})
        result['code'] = 200 if result['data'] else 404
        return make_response(dumps(result), result['code'],{"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

This should work, as python does some effort to resolve circular import dependencies: When it start importing a module, it creates an empty module dict for that one. Then when it finds a nested import, it proceeds with that one. If that in turn imports a module that is already in the import process it just skips it. Thus at the time `Contact.py` is being loaded, the `import rest_api` just takes the module dict that is already there. Since it does not contain `dbcollection` yet, `from rest_api import dbcollection` fails. A simple `import rest_api` does work however, since it's member is only addressed after `Contact.py` finishes importing (unless you call `Contact.get` at module level from within).

Comment: Hm.. wasn't aware of this but I am not sure its an ideal approach. noted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't a clue which modules are going to import which ever other ones, you can track that yourself and NOT do the import.

In your __init__.py, define these --

```
__module_imports__ = {}

def requires_module(name):
    return name not in __module_imports__

def importing_module(name):
    __module_imports__[name] = True
```

Then, at the top of each class file, where you define your classes add the following to this_module.py:

```
from my_modules import requires_module, importing_module

importing('ThisModule')
if requires_module('ThatModule')
    from my_modules.that_module import ThatModule

class ThisModule:
    """ Real Stuff Goes Here """
    pass
```

and this to that_module.py:

```
from my_modules import requires_module, importing_module

importing('ThatModule')
if requires_module('ThisModule')
    from my_modules.this_module import ThisModule

class ThatModule:
    """ Real Stuff Goes Here """
    pass
```

now you get your imports regardless of which gets imported first or whatever.